# How to use $.param with an object inside an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, param

I have an array that contain several objects and I want to use param to convert the array into a string. Is there a way to do that? Here is the code I have so far.

```
var spRates = [];

var object =    {
    'name': 'something',
    'rate': {900:30}, // this is what is not working
    'value': 'something'
};

spRates.push(object);

var spRatesString = $.param(spRates, true);

console.dir(spRates);

console.dir(spRatesString); // result: something=something
```

And this is the array (before using $.param)

[image]

Comment: Why are you calling the `param` on the array and not on the object?

Comment: [`jQuery.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) only supports serializing an array of name/value objects -- "*If the object passed is in an Array, it must be an array of objects in the format returned by [.serializeArray()](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)*."

Comment: ok thanks. I will use: $.param(spRates[0]); which does work: name=something&rate%5B900%5D=30&value=something. Thanks.